# NIntegrate crashes kernel

Tags: numerical-integration, crash

I am trying to evaluate numerically an integral of a function which depends on some parameters which I need to vary within a given range. Here are the definitions I use:

```
m2[x_, m02_, l2_, p_] = m02/(1 + (x/l2)^(1 + p));
f[x_, a_, b_, m02_, l2_, p_] = b x Exp[-a x] + m2[x, m02, l2, p];
suppr[x_, as_, bs_] = x* bs*Exp[-as*x];
newf[x_, as_, bs_] = (1 + suppr[x, as, bs]) f[x, Rationalize[0.180], 
Rationalize[-0.719], Rationalize[0.371^2], Rationalize[0.634], 
Rationalize[0.1]];
newD[x_, as_, bs_] = 1/(x + newf[x, as, bs]);
newuD[x_, as_, bs_] = newD[x, as, bs] newf[x, as, bs];
```

So the final function I need to integrate is `s Log[1 - newuD[s, as, bs]]` in the interval `{s,0,Infinity}` (this function is well behaved in this interval); for this purpose I have defined:

```
newq[as_, bs_, wpr_] := NIntegrate[s Log[1 - newuD[s, Rationalize[as], 
Rationalize[bs]]], {s, 0, Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 50, 
WorkingPrecision -> wpr]
```

Here is the problem. For `as=bs=0` I can select any working precision I want:

```
In[1]:= newq[0, 0, 6]
Out[1]= 24.1143
In[2]:= newq[0, 0, 7]
Out[2]= 23.75709 
In[3]:= newq[0, 0, 10]
Out[3]= 23.75711286
```

However, if I choose non-zero values for the parameters I can get a result selecting working precision 6:

```
In[4]:= newq[0.1, 0.129, 6]
Out[4]= 34.8776
```

But selecting a higher precision (which I need) *invariably crashes the kernel and does not return any result*. I am running on version 11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit).

Any idea/workaround?

Comment: It doesn't happen under 11.2.
I doubt it is related, but may I suggest to pull out the Rationalize statements out of the definition of newf function? In this manner they will be evaluated only once, not for every function call. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Just using working precision this low to report the crash, which, incidentally, will also happen choosing a different integration method such as "LocalAdaptive"

Answer (score 1):

Problems arise due to overflow with E^s in numerator and denominator.

First calculating the terms with that E^s... and than taking Log helps as workaround.

```
NIntegrate[logint = newuD[s, 0, 0]; 
   s Log[1 - logint], {s, 0, \[Infinity]}, WorkingPrecision -> 40, 
         MaxRecursion -> 100]

(*   23.75712157250552910577356711075917849924   *)

NIntegrate[logint = newuD[s, 1/10, 129/1000]; 
   s Log[1 - logint], {s, 0, \[Infinity]}, WorkingPrecision -> 40, 
      MaxRecursion -> 100]

(*   34.52101133437542508965238453435432822158   *)
```

Comment: Thank you Akku14; however, on my version your workaround fails to solve the issue. On which version are you running?

Comment: I'm using version 8.0.  But I just notice, it even works without workaround, directly as you did first.

Comment: Yep, I don't crash the Kernel, but I get a MemoryAllocationFailure on 11.2 with wpr 7.  M8 has no trouble with wpr 100.